# progress dialog is not working while calling new MyAsyncTask().execute().get() Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-asynctask

how to show progress dialog on onPreExecute() of AsyncTask android below is my code
here in this onPreExecute() method progress dialog is not showing  on UI Thread

**//calling AsyncTask**

```
try {

        new XYZ().execute(employeeId, password).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


     class XYZ extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    ProgressDialog simpleWaitDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {


        simpleWaitDialog =  new ProgressDialog(TreeViewListDemo.this);
        System.out.println("fgfdgfgfgf"+simpleWaitDialog);
        simpleWaitDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        simpleWaitDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        simpleWaitDialog.setCancelable(true);


        simpleWaitDialog.show();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        String username = params[0];
        String password = params[1];
        // this is code for perfoming SOAP web services which is working    fine and getting data from server side
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not do `new XYZ().execute(employeeId, password).get();`.

Comment: this is my question Actually. May I know how do I ask the question.@PankajKumar

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `get()`, presumably from the UI thread.  From the documentation, the [`get()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) method:

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves
>   its result.

This means you block the UI thread so that it cannot show the progress dialog.  I think you want to replace the call to `get()` with [`execute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29)

Comment: @AmarRaj I've edited to suggest the method you should be calling

Comment: without get() I didn't get server data so that I am using get() method along with execute()method

Comment: What makes you think that you don't get the data?  Your comment in the code says that the network part is working...